# Iterating over list of list elements and returning error message if integer has certain value

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list of lists like this:

breadsticks = [["name1", 45, 140]["name2", 85, 95]]

The third (or no[2]) element in each list inside the big list is a result of a calculation with variables given by the user and can't be higher than 80. If it is higher than 80 I need to return an error message instead of printing the results of a calculation.

What I've tried so far:

```
i = 0
while i <= len(breadsticks):
     if breadsticks[i][2] > 80:
         print("you have entered too many breadcrums")
     elif i == len(breadsticks):
         for bread in breadsticks:
              print(breadsticks[bread][2])
     i += 1
```

My attempt to do this not only does not work, it is also clumsy. Are there any other, smooth, ways to give error messages retarding things like this?

Comment: You almost never want to loop with `i = 0; while i <= spam: eggs … i += 1`. Just do `for i in range(spam): eggs …`. However, even that is rarely useful, because you can just do `for breadstick in breadsticks:` and not even worry about the indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`any()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) with a generator expression testing each nested list:

```
if any(bread[2] > 80 for bread in breadsticks):
    print("You have entered too many breadcrumbs")
```

This will only test as many nested lists as needed to find any for which the test is `True`.

Note that it is simpler to just loop *directly* over `breadsticks` in loops:

```
for bread in breadsticks:
    print(bread[2])
```